# spring batch null job runner null pointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, jobs, spring-batch, runner

Hi I'm getting null pointer exception while executing a sample spring batch job. Exception is thrown from job launcher. This is my job launcher code. Thanks in advance.

```
public class NewJobRunner {
public static Job job;
public static JobLauncher jobLauncher;
public static JobRepository jobRepository;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/resources/job-context.xml");
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .toJobParameters()
        );
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void setJobLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
}

public void setJobRepository(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
}

public void setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
}
```

Comment: hmmm all you members are static; basically if you have the right configs in job-context.xml this may work but you shouldn't work like this. I suggest you to remove static for members; declare in job-context a NewJobRunner; inject all the members and then  NewJobRunner newJobRunner = (NewJobRunner) applicationContext.getBean("newJobRunner"); 
newJobRunner.jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .toJobParameters()
        );

Comment: At which point you getting null point exception?please share the exception details.Probably the error is due to the invalid path '/resources/job-context.xml'